# Failed to open a session for the virtual machine on genymotion

Tags: genymotion

When I run genymotion, I got this error in the following screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of virtualization. You can solve this by enabling the virtualization option in your BIOS menu.
**Notice:** Your processor should support **virtualization**.

1. Restart your computer.
2. Open the BIOS menu (normally by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> -*depending on your PC*- before your PC boots on Ubuntu).
3. Go to **security** section, you will find the Virtualization
   option.
4. Enable the virtualization option.
5. Save and exit.

After restarting your PC, the virtualization should be enabled.